# How to display what i searched in the search box after getting resul

Tags: html

How to display what i searched in the search box after getting result...eg: if searched for apple in a search box after getting result how to display the apple in the search box

How to display what i searched in the search box after getting result

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the search box:

```
let searchTerm = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
```

Display the search term in the search box:

```
document.getElementById("search-box").value = searchTerm;
```

You can place this in the func that displays the search results. Then it updates the search box with the search term after displaying the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *localStorage* element in your code to store the current textbox value. It will stay until you remove it. For Example,

```
<form id="form1" action="#" method="post" >
    Selected Employee <input type="text"  name="EmployeeName" id="text1">
                     <input type ="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

and js part is,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#form1").submit(function () {
                window.localStorage['text1_val'] = $("input[id = 'text1']").val();
            });
            $(window).load(function () {
                $("input[id = 'text1']").val(window.localStorage['text1_val']);
            });
        });
```

You need jQuery in your code to run this code.
Hope this will help you.